# Postgresql update multiple rows with same name and id, and update the consecutive rows vrersion

Tags: postgresql

I have a table where insertion is in this form.

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Qkj9.png)

I want the verion to get update by 1 whenever there is a new row with same name and id.

[Required output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqeTw.png)

I tried using a function and trigger.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_ver()
  RETURNS TRIGGER 
  LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
  AS
$$
BEGIN
    update version
    set ver = ver + 1
    where new.name = 'A' and new.id ='1';
RETURN new;
END;
$$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-- create table
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    "name" varchar NULL,
    id int4 NULL,
    phone varchar NULL,
    email varchar NULL,
    ver int4 NULL
);

-- create trigger function
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION before_insert()
  RETURNS TRIGGER 
  LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
  AS
$$
begin
    new.ver = (select coalesce(max(ver), 0) + 1 from mytable where name = new.name and id = new.id);
    
    return new;
end;
$$

-- set trigger function to table
create trigger trg_before_insert before
insert
    on
    mytable for each row execute function before_insert();
    
-- inserting sample data    
INSERT INTO mytable ("name", id, phone, email) VALUES('A', 1, '123', '123@email.com');
INSERT INTO mytable ("name", id, phone, email) VALUES('B', 2, '345', '345@email.com');
INSERT INTO mytable ("name", id, phone, email) VALUES('A', 1, '456', '456@email.com');

-- select data and view
select * from mytable;


Result: 

name|id|phone|email        |ver|
----+--+-----+-------------+---+
A   | 1|123  |123@email.com|  1|
B   | 2|345  |345@email.com|  1|
A   | 1|456  |456@email.com|  2|
```